# Apache FOP. XSLT line-through works incorrectly inside a table cell

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to create a table with a struck through text inside cells. I need to render a PNG image using Apache FOP. When I build a PDF file it works correctly, but in a PNG image only even lines are getting crossed.

PDF is on the left, PNG is on the right:
[image]

XML:

```
<xml>
    <service-result-list>
        <service-result-item>
            <service-name>leg</service-name>
        </service-result-item>
        <service-result-item>
            <service-name>arm left</service-name>
        </service-result-item>
        <service-result-item>
            <service-name>head</service-name>
        </service-result-item>
        <service-result-item>
            <service-name>arm right</service-name>
        </service-result-item>
    </service-result-list>
</xml>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:attribute-set name="table-cell">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-family">ArialNarrow</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">7pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border">solid 1px black</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>

    <xsl:template name="table2">
        <fo:block-container>
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="527px" margin-left="1px">
                <fo:table-column column-width="527px"/>
                <fo:table-header text-align="center">
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-cell">
                            <fo:block>Service</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="service-result-list/service-result-item"/>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block-container>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="service-result-list/service-result-item">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-cell">
                <fo:block text-align="left" text-decoration="line-through"><xsl:value-of select="./service-name"/></fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Apache-Fop.